# how express-session and passport-local strategy works and what is its execution flow?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, session-cookies, passport-local

## how express-session and passport-local strategy works and what is its execution flow ?

In my node project I am using passport authentication with passport local strategy. I want know the entire workflow of `express-session , passport , passport-local-strategy`. what is the execution flow of these three modules and what happens when an user clicks on login.Please........! Brief me out about the complete execution flow.I want know the complete execution of these things.